# Capture other mouse button events on OS X with NSEvent

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-yosemite

I'm trying to capture mouse clicks on OS X Yosemite.

From what I've read this code should work:

```
[NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSOtherMouseDown
    handler:^(NSEvent *event) {
       NSLog(@"Mouse Down, Button: %ld", event.buttonNumber);
    }];
```

However, it only works for events on the right mouse button, not other buttons (i.e. buttons 4, 5, 6, et cetera on multi-button mice).

Using Quartz Event Taps I'm able to detect mouse clicks on these buttons, like so:

```
CGEventTapCreate(kCGSessionEventTap,
                 kCGHeadInsertEventTap,
                 0,
                 CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventOtherMouseUp) | CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventOtherMouseDown),
                 MouseEventCallback,
                 NULL);
```

But I'd prefer to use the NSEvent API as it is more straightforward.

Any ideas on how to capture other mouse button events with NSEvent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possibly just a typo in your question ?, but your code is missing the NSEventMaskFromType, e.g.  :

```
[NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSEventMaskFromType(NSOtherMouseDown) ..
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Or just use `NSOtherMouseDownMask` directly.

Comment: That was exactly the problem! Thank-you.

Comment: Hey Daniel and @KenThomases when I do `NSOtherMouseDownMask` is there like an associated number with the other buttons? I got the standard left button, right button, middle btn, v wheel, h wheel, but like if they have 3 extra buttons on their mouse are they like numbered and can i tell in this event?

Comment: @Noitidart, yes. `NSEvent` has a `buttonNumber` property you can examine to learn which button it was.

Comment: Thanks Ken! Sweetness!